# react-native-webview: is there a way to determine when we are done redirecting (with multiple redirections)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Using `react-native-webview`, I redirect my users to an URL that will redirect to other URLs that will all redirect, multiple times.
I don't know how many redirections there are, or even the end-URL.

Is there a way to know when the webview is done redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

You could send a message from the end-URL to your server when the client lands on it, which idicates that the website is done redirecting. If you don't own the URLs where your client gets redirected to, you must know how many times the client gets redirected, so you can calculate a time-astimate with the default ping of the client plus a buffer...

Something like that: done_redirecting = avg_ping * redirecting_amount + buffer

Please note that this is pseudo-code and theoretical.

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned above, I don't know how many redirections there are or the end-URL :/
Otherwise the calculation of the time-estimate would have been a good idea.

Comment: so method 1 also doesnt work (sending msg to server when destiny-page has rendered)?

Comment: No, because I don't have the ownership of the destination page  :/

Comment: Do you have a maximum redirect amount? Can the client be redirected to infinity?

Comment: I don't have a maximum redirect amount, he could theoretically be redirected to infinity, even though he isn't ^^